# CakePHP first run - can't find index.php in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cakephp

I'm new to both CakePHP and Eclipse and am having a problem. I downloaded the framework and unzipped it to htdocs/caketest, where I see the directory structure, including index.php.

Then I opened the project in Eclipse. Last time it was fine, but today, I'm not able to locate index.php (or even other directories) in PHP explorer. Here's the screenshot:

[image: CakePHP on Eclipse]

When I execute the project, I can see that index.php is getting run and I'm getting a message saying that CakePHP is not configured. But why isn't the file showing up in PHP Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn! I just clicked Refresh and the missing files appeared. Some helpful editor Eclipse is! Sorry for posting this in a haste.

Comment: By the way, I absolutely hated CakePHP's conventions and have moved on to Yii. :P

Answer (score 0):

You should create app/tmp directory.

Comment: Well, like I said in my own answer below, refreshing the page seems to solve the problem. Thanks for the answer anyway! :-)